# Assigning Images to Dropdown selections Google Sheets

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the program that I currently have:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HD9jbJlMuAy8xXFfSFce0L21anmahk6ng3LdfFLnLqA/edit?usp=sharing

it pulls data from a sheet to create dropdown menus and then after relevant information is filled out, it creates an entry in another sheet.

I need a way to assign images to the dropdown menus, in such a way that when a dropdown option is picked - it will show the corresponding image on the bottom of the screen.

I've tried a couple of entries, but I keep getting errors such as "index doesn't exist" or similar.

This is what it looks like:
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDECa.png)

I am trying to have an image show up underneath the "submit" button when an "item code" is picked that corresponds to the one in column B

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expected as the image?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear the first time. I've edited and made my issue a little more understandable.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.